# JSON Array element comparion with Java Script Array in Angular 2

Tags: arrays, json, angular, object, if-statement

I am working on Angular 2 with type script and came up with a very peculiar problem.
I have a number array named empIds as

```
empIds = {1,5,6,9,2}
```

I have (a JSON Array) named empDetails (please note employeeId is string here)as

```
empDetails [{"employeeId":"1","employeeName":"Jhon"},
            {"employeeId":"2","employeeName":"Ron"},
            {"employeeId":"3","employeeName":"Van"}]
```

Now i have to find out the only JSON objects who's id match in number array.
Here is what i wrote

```
for(let i=0;i<empDetails.length;i++){
if(empIds.indexOf(empDetails[i].employeeId)==0 ){
//Employee ID is present save that JSON object to some other JSON Array
i should get details for matched id (1 and 2)
}else{
//Did not match
do nothing
}
}
```

i did put console.log for both if and else. My loop never matches it always goes to else condition?
Is there any possible solution?

Comment: Your `empIds = {1,5,6,9,2}` is not valid. It should be `empIds = [1,5,6,9,2]`. Change your condition from `if(empIds.indexOf(empDetails[i].employeeId)==0 ){` to `if(empIds.indexOf(empDetails[i].employeeId) >= 0 ){`

Comment: it did not help :(

Answer (score 1):

The code logic is incorrect. Check index if its greater than -1 
Should be as below

```
 let empIds = [1, 5, 6, 9, 2];
    let empDetails = [{ "employeeId": 1, "employeeName": "Jhon" },
    { "employeeId": 2, "employeeName": "Ron" },
    { "employeeId": 3, "employeeName": "Van" }]
    for (let i = 0; i < empDetails.length; i++) {
      if (empIds.indexOf(empDetails[i].employeeId) > -1) {
        console.log("found");
        console.log(empDetails[i])
      }
    }
```

Comment: Hi All, i made a mistake as the JSON array contains details as string and not numbers.[{ "employeeId": "1", "employeeName": "Jhon" },
    { "employeeId": "2", "employeeName": "Ron" },
    { "employeeId": "3", "employeeName": "Van" }]

Comment: Realized a bit late.. but thanks for all your support

Answer (score 0):

```
const newArray = empDetails.filter(item => empIds.includes(item.employeeId));
```

I think this is an ok way to get a new array with all the objects from **empDetails** that have the **employeeId** in **empIds**.

.includes() => returns true or false if the  **empIds** contains the employeeId

.filter() => returns all the objects that were true on the include call

```
empIds = [2];

empDetails = [{"employeeId":1,"employeeName":"Jhon"},
            {"employeeId":2,"employeeName":"Ron"},
            {"employeeId":3,"employeeName":"Van"}]
```

with my code the new array would be this

```
[{"employeeId":2,"employeeName":"Ron"}]
```

because only employeeId = 2 is in empIds table

Answer (score 0):

`var filtered = empDetails.filter( (e) => empIds.indexOf(parseInt(e.employeeId)) >= 0 );`

If you don't care about support for Internet explorer, you can also use [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#Browser_compatibility) (See answer by Hopless)